# Encryption between web service users

Tags: php, passwords, rsa, encryption

I've got a web service (similar to an online store) where users save their data. I need to encrypt that data, so that only managers and users themselves could read that data.

Every manager and user has his own password stored hashed in the database.

First i've thought to use RSA(public/private keys), but i can't figure out how to gain access to the encrypted data using different passwords of managers and users.

BTW: i can prompt user and manager to enter his password every time they try to access encrypted data (compare with hashed one in database and decrypt secured data).

Please help and excuse me for my poor English.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: the simplest way is to use hardcoded master-password for both encryption/decryption, but i think that is very very insecure.

EDIT2: ok, i think i've got the idea:
1. generate unique key
2. using symmetric encryption encrypt data with unique key from (1)
3. encrypt unique key from (1) with user's password and store it with user's credentials
4. encrypt unique key from (1) with manager's password and store it with manager's credentials

now when manager wants to access data, i prompt him for a password, then decrypt hash from (4), get unique key from (1) and decrypt secure data. decryption from user is the same: (3)->(1)->data

so now problem is to make this available for multiple users->user_data/managers, lol

EDIT3: forgot to mention: users create data once and then managers use it for internal use.

Comment: The problem with the approach you've outlined in EDIT2 is when the data is created, each user involved will have to enter their password.

Comment: @sidoh yep, that's right. from the user point of view it will seem that he creates data and secures it by his password. and even if hacker steals  database, he can't decrypt user data cause user's password is also hashed.

Comment: Right. My point is, though, that if you need to allow access to the data using more than one password, you'll always need to have at least two passwords at a time. This sounds annoying for the users, right? Every time a user creates data that the manager should be able to access, both the user and the manager will have to enter passwords.

Comment: Also, you'll have to keep N copies of the data, where N is the number of users you want to allow access.

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn't mention: users create data once and then managers use that data for creating internal use docs.

Comment: >Also, you'll have to keep N copies of the data, where N is the number of users you want to allow access. /no, in approach presented in EDIT2, i just need to store for everyone only unique key encrypted by user/manager password

Comment: Ah, that's true. But then you'll need N copies of the unique key, one for each encryption key you want to allow access to the data. And this still doesn't solve the most annoying problem -- you'll always need someone else's password when granting an additional user access.

Comment: @sidoh i have to agree, this is a problem. i'll keep thinking :) thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind prompting for the password every time the user needs to access the data, you might consider using the [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php) php module. Make sure to do your research before implementing anything, though. It's quite easy to use insecurely if you're not careful.

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of managers who can access secure data but the user who encrypted that data should also have access. The best solution could be is that user encrypts data with his password and managers can decrypt message with their own passwords. But i just can't figure out the algorithm.

Comment: This is quite complicated, and it seems like it'd be really easy to implement either insecurely or in a way that is difficult to use. Have you considered using a single, randomly-generated password that all users involved can share with something like lastpass?

Comment: no, users/managers do not know each other, and everybody can register at service, so sharing the password would be like sharing it with a hacker.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use standard - proven technologies. It sounds me like the way should be SSL connection and well secured server. I believe you definitely do not need to encrypt data, but just provide access only for its owners or by some privilege hierarchy (by webservice security logic). If you need to protect data against disk stole, use encrypted partition by operating system.

Comment: yep, AES or DES would be the best choice